# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO PLEASE HELP ME THIS IS MY FUNCTION AND STRUCTURE DEFINITION IT IS SHOWING ERROR AS error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector .
`

`````
typedef struct cord
{
    int cord[2],score;
}cord;
cord succesor(int space[][s],cord score)
{
    int i,j,k=0;
    cord min=score[0];
    while(k<4)
        {

            i=score[k].cord[0];
            j=score[k].cord[1];
            if(min.score<= score[k].score && space[i][j]!=-1 && i>=0 &&i<=s&&j>=0 &&j<=s)
            {
                min=score[k];s[0]=score[k].cord[0];s[1]=score[k].cord[1];
            }
}````
`````

Comment: This declaration of a parameter cord score declares a scalar object score. So it is unclear why you are using the subscript operator for example in this declaration cord min=score[0]; As for your question "What to do" then you need to read a book on C for beginners.

Comment: I cas you don't know yet, WRITING ALL CAPS is considered as rude. Not only here but about everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration `cord succesor(int space[][s],cord score)` declares the parameter `score` to be a single structure of type `cord`. This is not an array or a pointer. So, later in the code, `score[0]` and `score[k]` cannot work because `score` is not an array or pointer.

You may want to declare the parameter as `cord *score`. This would declare it to be a pointer, which the function can use with subscript notation.